# Why isn't my React Native animation working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck to this section of code and I can't understand and solve this problem. I tried also just not using an animation but in my code if I put a view inside of another view, the view children will not show.

```
import Home from "../src/Home.js";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { SafeAreaView, Animated, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image} from 'react-native';


export default function HomePage() {
  const [fadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))  // Initial value for opacity: 0

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(
      fadeAnim,
      {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 10000,
        useNativeDriver: true
      }
    ).start();
  })

  return (
    <View style={{
      flex:1,
      backgroundColor: '#00D1FF',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    }}>
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: fadeAnim}}> 
      <Image source={require('../assets/logoLogo.png')} style={{
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        width: '50%',
        height: '15%',
      }}/>
   </Animated.View> 
    </View>
  );
}
```

Please if anyone of you guys knows what is going on. Thanks!!

Comment: Please see [ask] to learn how to improve your question post, and take the [tour] to learn why you shouldn't have posted the answer below.

Comment: Try without percentage for width/height, use 100/100 for example, or try setting `flex: 1` to `Animated.View`

Comment: try changing useState with useRef, also check when to use useState and useRef and React at all.

Comment: I tried using useRef and setting flex:1 but still nothing is showing up.